# Manipulating web content without having to make changes to the web server or content

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I want to be able to manipulate web content coming from my web servers without making any changes to them or the content. Kind of a dynamic content proxy.

It seems a reverse proxy server such as NGinx or Squid can provide a suitable platform for developing a module that would plugin into it and intermediate the flow of content between the web server content and client.

Is this a wise way of going forward with this, performance and architecture wise? Can anyone advise on other possible paths or solutions that can start me off here?

Comment: have found this Nginx module: nginx_substitutions_filter.
interesting to see how it compares to Apache's mod_substitute as far as performance and options.